# mongoose: Best way to get values for an object before save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I need to access a property but just id is send.

my request body example:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "quantity": 3,
        "product": "5d33fc0ac8c7a56d62cd6ac6"
    }
],
"user": "5d33fdafc8c7a56d62cd6ac9"
```

}

I need get price of product and multiply by quantity

```
async create(createOrderDto: CreateOrderDto): Promise<IOrder> {
try {
        const order = new this.orderSchema(createOrderDto);
        order.items.map(item => item.subtotal = item.product.price * item.quantity));
        return await this.orderSchema.create(order);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.message);
    }
}
```

**item.product.price** Error message: 'Property 'price' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'.ts(2339)'

how transform item.product to Product.Schema or something ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `map` will replace the list element with the return value of the given function, in your case `item.product.price * item.quantity`. You want to have `item` as a return value instead.

---

Consider

```
let items = [{price: 3, quantity: 2}];
items = items.map(item => item.subtotal = item.price * item.quantity)
```

Then `items` will be `[6]`.

Instead you should do:

```
let items = [{price: 3, quantity: 2}];
items = items.map(item => {
    item.subtotal = item.price * item.quantity);
    return item;
});
```

Here `items` will be `[{price: 3, quantity: 2, subtotal: 6}]`.